# UIAlert - change message font size IOS7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I have a working UIalert view  with text field and 2 buttons.

I want the text in the message to be a bit bigger, how can I do it?

thanks,
Shlomi

Comment: You can not change font of title or the message

Answer (score 1):

The `UIAlertView` cannot be changed. If you wish to modify it, you will need to create your own from scratch.

Please see the [UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), and under subclassing notes:

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.